# What does the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_A:S\to\mathbb{R}$ do?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

**Exercise:** Let $(S,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $A\subseteq S$. Show that $A\in\mathcal{A}$ if and only if $\mathbb{1}_A:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

I think I understand how I should solve this exercise. What I don't understand is what the mapping $\mathbb{1}_A:S\to\mathbb{R}$ does. In this case $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function (I checked with my professor), which has a range of $\{0,1\}$. Hence, I would expect the mapping to be $\mathbb{1}_A:S\to\{0,1\}$.

**Question:** Why is the function $\mathbb{1}_A$ defined from $S\to\mathbb{R}$ instead from $S\to\{0,1\}$?

Comment: A real-valued function $f$ is measurable (by definition) if $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all Borel sets $B \subset \mathbb{R}$. Often measurability of functions is [at first] only defined for real-valued or extended-real-valued functions. If a more general concept of measurability of functions is not yet defined, using $\mathbb{R}$ as the codomain is [almost] the only option.

Comment: @DanielFischer So it's just notation for the (temporarily) missing of a more general definition?

Comment: In probability theory a random variable is defined to be a measurable function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. So taking $\mathbb R$ as codomain has the advantage that $1_A$ can be recognized as a random variable. I don't see any disadvantages. It is just handsome. More broad e.g. $\sin$ is defined as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and not as a function $\mathbb R\to[-1,1]$.

Comment: Taking $\mathbb{R}$ as the codomain has other advantages too. One can then naturally multiply indicator functions with real-valued functions, which is quite useful.